# Flex circular ripple effect

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, effects

I want to create a circular water ripple effect in Flex. Does anyone know any example, source code, or have a general idea of how they would accomplish this?

Comment: you might want to check out: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/filters/DisplacementMapFilter.html

Comment: I vote for DisplacamentMapFilter and some kind of a radial gradient with lots of black and white stripes. You will probably want to animate the gradient itself and reassign the filter after that. With PixelBender the learning curve is quite steep unless you find a filter that does exactly what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Pixel Bender](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/pixelbender/).  There are a couple of examples that turn up with [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=pixel+bender+ripple).